# Check if any part of a hashtable value contains certain string c#

Tags: c#, winforms, list, hashtable

I deserialise a file into a hashtable of which the keys contain file paths like, `"c:\test\file.txt"` and `"c:\store\etc.txt"` for example. I then need to check if part of a path `"c:\"` or `"c:\test"` is included in one of those hashtable keys. So if `"C:\test\file.txt"` contains `"C:\test"` return `true`.

I can do this simply with a list below (lstLoadedNodes is the List) which works great:

```
if (lstLoadedNodes.Any(s => s.Contains(e.Node.Path)))
```

I can't find a way to do this with a hashtable without the whole key needing to be matched.

When I attempt this with a hashtable (checkedNodes is my hashtable) it only returns `true` if the exact string matches:

```
if (checkedNodes.ContainsKey(e.Node.Path))
```

How can I search any part of the hashtable.key? Hope that makes sense!

I know I can pass all the values to a list first and then perform the "if contains.any" which is what i'm currently doing but this seems pointless so I'd rather just check the hashtable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could implement your own data structure. E.g. based on a tree (split path by '/') where children are held in a hashtable.

Comment: `if (lstLoadedNodes.Any(s => s.Contains(e.Node.Path)))` will work for a `HashSet`.

Comment: mjwills - that doesn't work for me for some reason, the ".Any" errors.

Comment: using a HashTable

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using `Hashtable` rather than `Dictionary<type, type>`?

Comment: suppose just the way program started, is a Dictionary better/quicker? Fairly new to C#

Comment: @acurachris Yes a Dictionary is better / quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
checkedNodes.Keys.Cast<string>().Any(k => k.Contains(e.Node.Path));
```

Comment: @acurachris Glad to here that~  : )