# Delete a record by matching Value

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have a dictionary where values are stored in the following format -

```
userID, empDetails
```

For example,

```
1234, 'empName,jobDesc,CardNumber,Type'
```

I have to compare this information with another set of information such that -

- If entered userId is present in the above dictionary, then remove this record from the dictionary.
- If entered CardNumber is present (here userId is not known) in the above dictionary, then remove this record from the dictionary.

The first condition is simple and can be done by

```
dictionary.Remove(key)
```

But I am confused as to how would I implement the second condition. I want something like

```
if(CardNumber.PresentinAboveDictionary)
then
Remove that record
```

I know we can compare a partial string in a key like this, but I want to remove the record.
[Check if any part of a hashtable value contains certain string c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45736468/check-if-any-part-of-a-hashtable-value-contains-certain-string-c-sharp)

Comment: does the dictionary have large number of records?

Comment: @NitinSawant they would be around thousands.

Comment: better you use some other efficient data structure.

Comment: Are you concerned with performance or just need a working solution?

Comment: @SBFrancies  First preference will be working solution, but yes performance is also an importance factor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the employment details in your dictionary are a string in the specified format you would need to:

1. Search the values within the dictionary
2. Parse/Split the values to get the card numbers
3. Check the card numbers to see if they match the card number you are checking
4. Return the key value pair when a match occurs
5. Remove the entry for the key in the returned key value pair

Example code for the solution:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>() { { 1, "empName,jobDesc,124124134,Type" } };
                
var cardNumber = 124124134;
var entry = dictionary.FirstOrDefault(x => DoEmploymentDetailsContainCardNumber(x.Value, cardNumber));

if (!entry.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<int, string>)))
{
    dictionary.Remove(entry.Key);
}
```

Method that checks if card number is present in employment details:

```
private static bool DoEmploymentDetailsContainCardNumber(string empDetails, int cardNumber)
{
    var splitEmpDetails = empDetails.Split(',');
    var empDetailsCardNumber = splitEmpDetails[2];
    return empDetailsCardNumber == cardNumber.ToString();
}
```

Comment: you are iterating all elements and applying split to all and then comparing, which takes longer if there are thousands of elements

Comment: Longer than what?

Comment: This solution doesn't take into account the possibility that card numbers may not be unique - maybe they always are but it's not stated by the questioner as far as I can tell.

Comment: @SBFrancies It's implied by the language used in the question, otherwise the grammar is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Dictionary` you can use a strongly typed `List`

1. Use the Linq builtin `Remove` method
2. Use `Parallel.ForEach`, iterate the list and remove the item (beware, takes more time)

pseudo code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public Employee(int userID, string empDetails)
        {
            string[] props = empDetails.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            this.userID = userID;
            this.empName = props[0];
            this.jobDesc = props[1];
            this.CardNumber = props[2];
            this.Type = props[3];
        }

        public int userID { get; set; }
        public string empName { get; set; }
        public string jobDesc { get; set; }
        public string CardNumber { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyCustomList : List<Employee>
    {
        public void Add(int userID, string empDetails)
        {
            this.Add(new Employee(userID, empDetails));
        }

        public bool Remove(string CardNumber)
        {
            bool found = false ;
            Parallel.ForEach(this,
            (i, state) =>
            {
                if (i.CardNumber == CardNumber)
                {
                    this.Remove(i);
                    state.Break();
                }
            });
            return found;
        }

        public bool RemoveV2(string CardNumber)
        {
            bool found = false;
            if (this.Any(x => x.CardNumber == CardNumber))
            {
                this.Remove(this.Where(x => x.CardNumber == CardNumber).First());
                found = true;
            }
            return found;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dict = new MyCustomList();//userID, empDetails list
            dict.Add(12341, "empName1,jobDesc,CardNumber1,Type");
            dict.Add(12342, "empName2,jobDesc,CardNumber2,Type");
            dict.Add(12343, "empName3,jobDesc,CardNumber3,Type");
            dict.Add(12344, "empName4,jobDesc,CardNumber4,Type");
            dict.Add(12345, "empName5,jobDesc,CardNumber5,Type");
            dict.Add(12346, "empName6,jobDesc,CardNumber6,Type");
            dict.Add(12347, "empName7,jobDesc,CardNumber7,Type");
            dict.Add(12348, "empName8,jobDesc,CardNumber8,Type");

            //remove CardNumber5
            dict.Remove("CardNumber5");
            Console.Write(dict);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the simple approach to remove the key by using a loop here.

Here I am assuming that there is no key with a value of -1 in the dictionary.

```
int keyToRemove = -1;
foreach (var entry in dictionary)
{
    if (entry.Value.Contains(CardNumber))
    {
        keyToRemove = entry.Key;
        break;
    }
}

if (keyToRemove != -1)
{
    dictionary.Remove(keyToRemove);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly overkill and is not optimised for reading the full dataset repeatedly but it is considerably faster than the accepted solution. I put together a test of the solution below which did the following:

1. Generated 1,000,000 data rows with unique IDs and card numbers (the solution would also work if the card numbers were not unique)
2. Randomly removed 100,000 data items by ID and 100,000 data items by card number
3. Generated a list of the remaining data items

The process took around 75 seconds.

I then tried to repeat steps 1) and 2) using the accepted answer - after around 10 minutes it's about 7% of the way through removing data items. Therefore I think the solution below is around 2 orders of magnitude faster for this type of operation.

There are probably better doubley linked list implementations out there but I am not too familiar with any of them.

```
namespace Question
{
    public class EmployeeCollection 
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<int, ListNode<EmployeeDetails>> _idDictionary = new();
        private readonly Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, EmployeeDetails>> _cardNumberDictionary = new();
        private readonly LinkedList<EmployeeDetails> _list = new();

        public void AddEmployee(EmployeeDetails details)
        {
            var node = new ListNode<EmployeeDetails>(details);
            _list.AddToStart(node);
            _idDictionary.Add(details.Id, node);
            
            if(!_cardNumberDictionary.ContainsKey(details.CardNumber))
            {
                _cardNumberDictionary.Add(details.CardNumber, new Dictionary<int, EmployeeDetails>());
            }

            _cardNumberDictionary[details.CardNumber].Add(details.Id, details);
        }

        public void RemoveById(int id)
        {
            if (_idDictionary.TryGetValue(id, out var node))
            {
                _idDictionary.Remove(id);
                _list.Remove(node);
                var list = _cardNumberDictionary[node.Value.CardNumber];
                list.Remove(id);

                if(list.Count == 0)
                {
                    _cardNumberDictionary.Remove(node.Value.CardNumber);
                }
            }
        }

        public void RemoveByCardNumber(string cardNumber)
        {
            if (_cardNumberDictionary.TryGetValue(cardNumber, out var employees))
            {
                _cardNumberDictionary.Remove(cardNumber);

                foreach (var employee in employees)
                {
                    if (_idDictionary.TryGetValue(employee.Key, out var node))
                    {
                        _list.Remove(node);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<EmployeeDetails> Employees => _list.GetAllValues();

        public EmployeeDetails? GetById(int id)
        {
            if(_idDictionary.ContainsKey(id))
            {
                return _idDictionary[id].Value;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    public class EmployeeDetails
    {
        public int Id { get; init; }
        public string Name { get; init; }
        public string JobDescription { get; init; }
        public string CardNumber { get; init; }
        public string Type { get; init; }

        public static EmployeeDetails FromData(int id, string details)
        {
            var parts = details.Split(',');

            return new EmployeeDetails
            {
                Id = id,
                Name = parts[0],
                JobDescription = parts[1],
                CardNumber = parts[2],
                Type = parts[3],
            };
        }
    }

    public class LinkedList<T>
    {
        public int Count { get; private set; }
        private ListNode<T>? Start { get; set; }
        private ListNode<T>? End { get; set; }
        public bool IsEmpty => Count == 0;

        public void AddToStart(ListNode<T> node)
        {
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(nameof(node));
            node.Next = null;
            node.Previous = null;

            if (IsEmpty)
            {
                Start = End = node;
            }
            else
            {
                Start!.Previous = node;
                node.Next = Start;
                Start = node;
            }

            Count++;
        }

        public void Remove(ListNode<T> node)
        {
            if (node != Start)
            {
                node.Previous!.Next = node.Next;
            }

            else
            {
                Start = node.Next;
            }

            if (node != End)
            {
                node.Next!.Previous = node.Previous;
            }

            else
            {
                End = node.Previous;
            }

            Count--;
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> GetAllValues()
        {
            var counter = Start;

            while (counter != null)
            {
                yield return counter.Value;
                counter = counter.Next;
            }
        }
    }

    public class ListNode<T>
    {
        public T Value { get; }
        public ListNode<T>? Previous { get; set; }
        public ListNode<T>? Next { get; set; }

        public ListNode(T value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like this.

```cs
var recordsToRemove = dictionary.Where(x => x.Value.Contains("what you are looking for"))
                                .ToList();

        if (recordsToRemove.Any())
        {
            foreach (var record in recordsToRemove)
            {
                dictionary.Remove(record.Key);
            }
        }
```